# Dynamic dropdown menu with bootstrap not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have been using bootstrap for a while, and I came across an issue when trying to add a dropdown menu dynamically.

This is the JavaScript that I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#clickHere").click(function(){
        $("#appendHere").html("<div class=\"dropdown\" style=\"display:inline;\"><a id=\"drop1\" href=\"#\" class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\"><b class=\"caret\"></b></a><ul class=\"dropdown-menu pull-left\"><li><button>Analyse Now</button></li><li class=\"divider\"></li><li><button>Analyse Later</button></li></ul></div>");
 });

 $('#drop1').on('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown('toggle');
 });
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" style="display: block; position: static; margin-bottom: 5px; *width: 180px;">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu pull-left"> <a tabindex="-1" href="#">More options</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="mainMenu">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<button id="clickHere">Click here </button>
<div id="appendHere"></div>
```

Here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/szx4Y/83/

The dropdown added dynamically does not work properly. I have managed to make it work in my code, but it only appears once anyway.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: @MilchePatern - The anchor element has the class `dropdown-toggle`.  The selector is valid.

Comment: Could you be more clear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a working jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/szx4Y/85/.

FYI, your jsFiddle didn't work because you didn't include the Bootstrap script file.  So if you were doing any testing there that wouldn't have worked.

I changed your code to call `$(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();` immediately after you append your HTML.  By calling that method you are setting up the elements to handle all the Bootstrap functionality (click events, etc); there's no reason to call it every time you click your new element.

### Relevant Code

**HTML**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" style="display: block; position: static; margin-bottom: 5px; *width: 180px;">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu pull-left"> <a tabindex="-1" href="#">More options</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="mainMenu">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<button id="clickHere">Click here </button>
<div id="appendHere"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clickHere").click(function(){
            $("#appendHere").html("<div class=\"dropdown\" style=\"display:inline;\"><a id=\"drop1\" href=\"#\" class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\"><b class=\"caret\"></b></a><ul class=\"dropdown-menu pull-left\"><li><button>Analyse Now</button></li><li class=\"divider\"></li><li><button>Analyse Later</button></li></ul></div>");
    });

    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.dropdown-menu {
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: I'd like to mention that you don't need to call `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();` at all and it will still work fine. Calling it once in the ready event does nothing anyway because no element with class `.dropdown-toggle` exists at the time of calling.

Comment: Can I add HTML content to the dropdown and use it as a modal dialog?