# Bootstrap v3.3.6 dropdown menu not working with dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm adding the following code dynamically with JS, in a ajax call, using:

```
document.getElementById('parent').innerHTML = data;
```

code

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Men<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Branded Golfers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Plain Casual T-Shirts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Branded casual T-Shirts</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How do I make the menu dropdown? I have a custom js bootstrap script, that handles the dropdown, that I include in my HTML page. If I write the code directly in the HTML body then the menu drops down but when I add it dynamically then it doesn't drop. I'm building on [this website template](https://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page236/dailyshop) but instead of hardcoding the menu, I want to add the menu dynamically. I have read some of the other links, here on stacks, regarding this issue but I didn't find an exact match. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I tried

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //populate main
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/getMainMenu.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.length > 1) {
                document.getElementById('main_menu').innerHTML = data;
                $('.dropdown-menu').dropdown()
            }
        }
    });
});
```

...but it's still not working.

My HTML markup looks like so:

```
<!-- menu -->
  <section id="menu">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="menu-area">
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>          
          </div>
          <div id="main_menu" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>       
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- / menu -->
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Dynamic dropdown menu with bootstrap not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20247981/dynamic-dropdown-menu-with-bootstrap-not-working)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], along with debugging details, if the duplicate link did not help you solve the issue. Any error in the console? etc.